# QGIS split feature tool is giving me an error

Tags: qgis

I'd like to split a feature into two features. This seems like it should be simple > I selected the feature > Used the split feature tool > selected outside the polygon on one side, and outside the polygon on the other side > Right clicked. Then it gave me this error.

"No features were split: If there are selected features, the split tool only applies to those. I you would like to split all features under the split line, clear the selection."

If I de-select the feature, I get the following error message.

"No feature split done: The geometry is invalid. Please repair before trying to split it.

Answer (score 3):

The question is generic, you do not specify the source of the geometries (shapefile, postgis, spatialite...), wether exists a spatial index (a corrupt spatial index may cause a similar issue)...

According to the error message you are receiving, though, the geometry you are trying to split seems to be invalid.

Try the "Check validity" plugin or "Fix geometry" process (save a copy of your data before to apply them). If QGis is unable to automatically correct the geometry, search for autointersection ("butterfly" shape) or duplicate nodes.

You may refer to: https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity
for a definition of what a valid geometry is.

Comment: The Check Validity tool worked, there were indeed errors in my polygons - I wasn't aware I could do that check, so that's fab! Thanks.